# Redis on heroku without RedisToGo add-on

Tags: heroku, redis, redistogo

Can we use redis on heroku for background jobs with python without using RedisToGo add-on. Any pointer please.

I've this error while following this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq post without using RedisToGo add-on

```
app[worker.1]: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does not include a redis server by default. You will have to use a Heroku add-on or connect to another instance you control.